# Criteria based estimation of a task's due date

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

Basically we have a ticket system, each day we get multiple tickets with different categorization (Question,Change,Error) and importance (High,Mid,Low) for different customers (A,B,C). My job is to create some kind of a system determining the due date of these "tasks" based on

- The state of the previous ones, completed or not.
- The availability of the developers.
- A criteria of the previously mentioned attributes (categorization,importance and customer
  type).

knowing that each ticket has variable number of hours needed to finish it.

How can one achieve that?

Comment: Due date, or completion time? First one is an external imposition ("error, high has to be resolved in a week"), the completion time does depend on available resources.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, or in scope for this site.  You're basically asking a question about tasks in your system, not a question about computer science.  How would we know how long a task will take?  That depends on the nature of the task and the nature of the resources available to perform the task.

Comment: the Developers and their working hours (the resources) are constants, and the number of hours needed to finish the task is an estimated variable given to every ticket.

But I think you're right, i don't believe i phrased the question properly to be considered a computer science problem.